# Where I can find original CentOS RPM Spec files?

Tags: centos, rpm, rpm-spec

Recently CentOS upgraded from 7.5 to 7.6 and now one of the packages upgraded to a newer version I'm not ready to use yet. I'm planning instead to build and support an older version of this package.

I wonder if there a way to extract or see (perhaps even versioned) original spec files from which CentOS packages are built. Is there a source code repository for spec files which are used to build official EPEL packages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find all the source packages (SRPMs) in [the CentOS vault](http://vault.centos.org/); for example, you’ll find the source packages for 7.5 [here](http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/os/Source/SPackages/).

EPEL SRPMs are likewise available from Fedora (where they’re maintained); you’ll find the source packages for 7 [here](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel//7/SRPMS/Packages/).

Comment: Also check Fedora Pagure (https://pagure.io/) for the git repositories for Fedora EPEL packages.